# How to apply typeahead.js autocomplete search to search username by lastname<space>firstname from different columns of database in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Here I am using Typeahead.js autocomplete search jquery plugin in my laravel code. Can you please help me to apply typeahead.js autocomplete search to search username by lastname  firstname or by firstname  lastname both ways from different columns of database in Laravel ?

My Controller logic is -

```
    public function autocomplete(Request $request) {   
    $string = "%{$request->input('query')}%";
    $searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

       $users = Profile::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
        foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
            $q->orWhere('firstname', 'like', "%{$value}%")->orWhere('lastname', 'like', "%{$value}%")->orWhere('mobile', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        }
    })->get(array('firstname','lastname','mobile'));

    return response()->json($users); 
}
```

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($request->has('name'))
        {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($request)
            {
                return $q->where('first_name', 'LIKE', $request->input('name') . '%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%');
            });
        }
```

Comment: any other suggestions please

Comment: sir, i have edited my question please help me to solve this